# Inside python code, how do I run a .sh script?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Will it continue the code after it's run? Or will it stop at that line until the script is done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is the easiest way. It will not return until the executed program has terminated. Have a look at the other methods of the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) if you need different behaviour.

Comment: `subprocess.call` was deprecated in 3.5: [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) should be used instead.

Answer (score 8):

```
import os
os.system('./script.sh')
```

python script won't stop until sh is finished

Comment: "The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function." - for example using subprocess.call() will not execute a shell to run whatever you run so you won't have to take care of argument injection if you pass any dynamically generated arguments to your program.

Comment: You can also suggest subprocess.Popen -- this could allow you to control the execution, wait for it, terminate, etc. But as practice shows os.system often provides all the functionality you need.

Comment: subprocess.call provides the easy/simple API too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.call` but when using subprocess methods make sure you use `shell=True`. And executing it via system call in all these methods is blocking. The python script will complete and then go the next step.

Comment: No need to use shell=True.. Shellscripts with a shebang line (or even invoking the shell with the script as an argument) can be executed fine with exec()-style functions.